# Export QTP results to html report

Tags: testing, automation, qtp

I am a newbie to QTP. How can I export QTP results to an html report? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Run Results Viewer** you can choose `File -> Export To File...` where you can control how much of the data from the results will be exported to the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

In UFT/QTP 11.5, the test results can be exported to html/doc/pdf format by following the below steps:

In the UFT test results window;

1. Navigate to File->Export to File...
2. In the Export Run Results pop up window, choose the desired options and click on Export button
3. In Save As dialog box, select "HTML/DOC/PDF files" in "Save Type as field"
4. Click Save button

Now the test results would be saved in HTML/DOC/PDF format in the specified location..

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps in UFT to generate the HTML report everytime you run the script:

1. Navigate to tools -> Options -> General -> Run Sessions
2. **check** Automatically export run results when run session ends:
3. click on configure.
4. Then choose the desired path and options for the report you want to generate.